# Ember - How to share singletons between controllers

Tags: ember.js

I have a service which fetch urls and needs to be created as a singleton with an application specific configuration.

Several of my controllers need to use this service.

How can I create this service in one place, preferably in the application and share it between controllers so they can use it directly?

My modules are divided into different files, using requirejs.

URLService.js

```js
var urlService = URLService.create({config: {...} })
```

SomeController.js

```js
var SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({ 
  service: null
})
```

Application:

```js
App = Em.Application.create({
  SomeController: SomeController  <-- inject the urlService into SomeController.service
})
```

Is there a built in way or a best practice of doing this? or am I missing something in the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class that `extend` the `Controller` like you're already doing, and all your application controllers `extend` from it like so:

```js
// the service
var urlService = URLService.create({config: {...} })

// the base controller class
var BaseController = Em.Controller.extend({ 
    service: null,
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('service', urlService);
    }
});

// your controllers inheriting from your base controller already with the service instance
var SomeController1 = BaseController.extend(...);
var SomeController2 = BaseController.extend(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is not what I meant though, I'm using separate files via requirejs, meaning I don't have the closure capability of sharing the configured URLService just like that.
I thinking of using the requirejs dependency management to share and configure the service by using app specific configuration module, but I wanted to know if there is a better built in way of doing it in ember. Thanks for your answer and effort.